# Apache Kafka Delivery Order

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Suppose that I have a Kafka producer.

My consumer first writes message M1 to topic T1 on Kafka (via sync api) then writes message M2 to topic T2.

At that time a consumer is listening topic T1 and T2. Whenever it sees a message on topic T2 it looks for a related message on topic T1.

Is it guaranteed that whenever the consumer sees the message M2 on topic T2, it will see message M1 on topic T1? (Since M1 was written before M2)

Answer (score 2):

Kafka doc about guarantees

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_guarantees

- At a high-level Kafka gives the following guarantees:
- Messages sent by a producer to a particular topic partition will be appended in the order they are sent. That is, if a record M1 is sent by the same producer as a record M2, and M1 is sent first, then M1 will have a lower offset than M2 and appear earlier in the log.
- A consumer instance sees records in the order they are stored in the log.
  For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1 server failures without losing any records committed to the log.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's not guaranteed**

Kafka consumer isn't guaranteed to be reading the last messages on your topics, depending on traffic. 
In a peak situation, it's perfectly possible that your consumer is reading messages from minutes ago on a given topic, and up to date on another one.

Also, it means some serious tweaking to ensure that you can distribute your application correctly, regarding to partition affectation.

With the default behaviour of kafka consumers repartition, you wouldn't be able to have more than a single consumer, removing an important Kafka upside which is horizontal scalability.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you wanted to ask what you asked.

Yes, it is guaranteed that consumer will finally see both M1 and M2.

But it is **not** guaranateed that it will see M1 **before** seeing M2. It is perfectly allowed for it to see M2 and only then receive M1, arbitrary long period of time afterwards. By arbitrary long we are talking about milliseconds, not days of course.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it guaranteed that whenever the consumer sees the message M2 on topic T2, it will see message M1 on topic T1? (Since M1 was written before M2)

No, this is not guaranteed.

Kafka does not guarantee message ordering *across topics*.  For the record, see [Guarantees](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_guarantees) in the Apache Kafka docs for what exactly is being guaranteed.

In your case, you do have messages spread across topics (message `M1` is in topic `T1`, message `M2` is in topic `T2`), so there's no guarantee for when, relative to each other, messages `M1` and `M2` will be read/consumed.

Also, there's no guarantee with regards to the *time* (or time delta) when those two messages would eventually being read -- they could both be read within an interval of milliseconds, or seconds, etc.  (In practice though, messages will typically be consumed very quickly.)